# How to log out from fbsession?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

H,In my app a user can login to the app using facebook.I am able to login successfully using fbsession but i am not able to logout form fbsession.Once the user login to the app i have do manually log out from fbsession. but i am not able to log out from fbseesion. In my app when ever i click on login button its not directing  to login page its directly showing dialog page,where as for me i have to show login page every time in my app. 
here is my code

```
   - (IBAction)facebooklogin:(id)sender
 {
       [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_hometown"]
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

                                  switch (state) {
                                      case FBSessionStateOpen:
                                          [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                  NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
                                              }
                                              else
                                              {
                                                  // retrive user's details at here as shown below
                                                  NSLog(@"user   :%@",user);

                                                  NSDictionary *resultdict=[[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:user.first_name,@"FirstName",user.last_name,@"LastName",user.last_name,@"LastName",user.birthday,@"Birthday",user.username,@"Username",[user objectForKey:@"email"],@"Email",user.id,@"FBUserId", nil]autorelease];

                                                  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:resultdict forKey:@"FBUserDetails"];
                                                  NSString *userid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@social",user.id];
                                                  [self performSelector:@selector(checkSocialNetworkingRegisteredOrNot:) withObject:userid afterDelay:0.0f];
                                              }
                                          }];
                                          break;

                                      default:
                                          break;
                                  }
                              } ];
 }
```

/////////////////////////manually logout from fbsession ///////////

```
  - (IBAction)logoutmanullayInbackground:(id)sender
{
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[[FBSession activeSession] close];
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

}

Comment: Why you want to bother user each time with login form ? It's quite usually that you just login once and then it keeps your status. Of course you need to give them option to logout somewhere on demand. But I see no reason for login in with each request...

Comment: This line sounds right to logout: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation] - is it not working ?

Comment: my app is consumer app for a restaurant so every customer can log in

Comment: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation] it not working

Comment: It is working for me - I gave it a try. When are you doing it ? just after he is logged in ? Leave just this one line: [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

Comment: @Grzegorz Krukowski Its not working i tried it still its directly opening login view

Answer (score 1):

You are logging out (the fact you see the button say "Log in" again means you've successfully logged out). However, if you're using SSO (via either iOS integrated login, or the Facebook app), then when the user clicks "Log in" again, they won't be prompted (since the user on the App or device has already authorized your app).

To get around this (since you say you're making a restaurant app), you can uninstall the Facebook app (and remove the login from iOS), or you can log in with the FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView when you open the session.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/#openWithBehavior%3AcompletionHandler%3A

Comment: I have solved this problem by using  FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView